# Read date in different lengths and conjoined numbers in python

Tags: python

The date document is wrote like below

```
1060301 1030727 1041201 1060606 1060531 1060629 1060623 1060720
```

...and some of them like....

```
831008 751125 1060110 890731 700815 731022 1010724 980116
```

Which represent the date data of:

Year(2~3 character)/Month(2 characters)/Day(2 characters)
And some r blanks for leaking data

is there a way to read those data into arranged date type?

Comment: What did you try? Are they integers or strings? If numbers you could try smth like (`n` is one of your numbers): `ym, d = divmod(n, 100)` `y, m = divmod(ym, 100)`, `y + 1900, m, d`.

Comment: thank you! its string though.....but i will try this

Comment: Then you can rely on their lengths. If the length is 6 then simply add `"19"` in front of it, else (if length is 7), get the first 3 chars, convert them to int, add 1900, convert back to string (4 chars) and add it before the remaining part. You could also use the code from my previous comment, but prior to that you need to convert the string to integer.

Comment: oh that's great! thank u :DDD

Comment: oh, how about just add 19000000 for every converted int.....thank u so much!

Comment: Yeah, much simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So by reading 1060301, Im assuming thats year:106, month:03, and day:01, so perform different operations on the different lengthed numbers with this:

```
valuelist = []
value = ''
date = ''

file = open('testfile.txt','r+')
filetowriteto = open('OUTPUTFILE','a+')

for line in file:
    for char in line:
        if char == ' ':
            if len(value) == 6:
                date = value[0:2]+'/'+value[2:4]+'/'+value[4:]
            elif len(value)==7:
                date = value[:3]+'/'+value[3:5]+'/'+value[5:]

            valuelist.append(date)
            value = ''
            date = ''
        else:
            value += char
            continue
for t in valuelist:
    filetowriteto.write(t+' ')

file.close()
filetowriteto.close()
```

Please don't hesitate to comment about anything.

Comment: thank u that make me a lot of idea to handling stuff :D thank again

Comment: No problem, I was't sure of how you wanted the output, but since you said _is there a way to read those data into arranged date type?_ I assumed you wanted it in a file; also be aware that running this multiple times in the same directory will add to the same file 'OUTPUTFILE'.

Comment: Thanks, you are so sweet :DD, i think i will try several kinds of output for different models. Totally new to coding work